# How to map() over 2nd item in JSON object

Tags: javascript

How do we map over the second item in a JSON object? I am using an API that is passing me meta data in the first item, i need to map over the second item.

Example response (converted to a JavaScript variable)

```js
const data = {
    "PaginationResponse": {
        "RequestedLimit": 100,
        "RequestedOffset": 0,
        "PageSize": 3,
        "TotalResults": 3
    },
    "SessionTypes": [
        {
            "Type": "Appointment",
            "DefaultTimeLength": 60,
            "Id": 5,
            "Name": "Basic Hair Cut",
            "NumDeducted": 1,
            "ProgramId": 2,
            "Category": "Hair salon",
            "CategoryId": 9,
            "Subcategory": "Haircut",
            "SubcategoryId": 2
        },
        {
            "Type": "Appointment",
            "DefaultTimeLength": 60,
            "Id": 6,
            "Name": "Fancy Signature Cut ",
            "NumDeducted": 1,
            "ProgramId": 2,
            "Category": "Hair salon",
            "CategoryId": 9,
            "Subcategory": "Haircut",
            "SubcategoryId": 2
        },
        {
            "Type": "Appointment",
            "DefaultTimeLength": 90,
            "Id": 27,
            "Name": "Fitting",
            "NumDeducted": 1,
            "ProgramId": 9,
            "Category": "Other",
            "CategoryId": 17,
            "Subcategory": "Other",
            "SubcategoryId": 418
        },
      ]
};
```

with help from community member @0stone0 i tried:

```js
data.SessionTypes.map(type => {
  console.log(type.Name);
});
```

but the result also returns `undefined` for each item in the array:

```js
[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
'Basic Hair Cut'
'Fancy Signature Cut '
'Fitting'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Also, [here's the documentation for `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map returns a new  array of return values of callback and here, you're not returning anything from callback. So the function(here callback) we'll implicitly return undefined. And you'll get array of undefined. However,you'll log the `type.name` to console each time.To get the `type.name` inside and array which map returns you should return it from callback. So if you want array of `type.name` of each object then you should do this.

```
const names = data.SessionTypes.map(type => {
       console.log(type.Name);//this well log to the console.
       return type.Name;//this will push the element to array.
});
```

or

```
const names = data.SessionTypes.map(type => type.Name);
```

And then you can iterate over names array.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `data.SessionTypes` like so:

```js
const data = {"PaginationResponse": {"RequestedLimit": 100, "RequestedOffset": 0, "PageSize": 25, "TotalResults": 25 }, "SessionTypes": [{"Type": "Appointment", "DefaultTimeLength": 60, "Id": 5, "Name": "Basic Hair Cut", "NumDeducted": 1, "ProgramId": 2, "Category": "Hair salon", "CategoryId": 9, "Subcategory": "Haircut", "SubcategoryId": 2 }, {"Type": "Appointment", "DefaultTimeLength": 60, "Id": 6, "Name": "Fancy Signature Cut ", "NumDeducted": 1, "ProgramId": 2, "Category": "Hair salon", "CategoryId": 9, "Subcategory": "Haircut", "SubcategoryId": 2 } ] };

data.SessionTypes.map(sessionType => {
  console.log(sessionType.Name);
});
```

---

Based on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682696/how-to-map-over-2nd-item-in-json-object/68682744?noredirect=1#comment121380718_68682744) and edit, OP's code:

```js
const data = {"PaginationResponse": {"RequestedLimit": 100, "RequestedOffset": 0, "PageSize": 3, "TotalResults": 3 }, "SessionTypes": [{"Type": "Appointment", "DefaultTimeLength": 60, "Id": 5, "Name": "Basic Hair Cut", "NumDeducted": 1, "ProgramId": 2, "Category": "Hair salon", "CategoryId": 9, "Subcategory": "Haircut", "SubcategoryId": 2 }, {"Type": "Appointment", "DefaultTimeLength": 60, "Id": 6, "Name": "Fancy Signature Cut ", "NumDeducted": 1, "ProgramId": 2, "Category": "Hair salon", "CategoryId": 9, "Subcategory": "Haircut", "SubcategoryId": 2 }, {"Type": "Appointment", "DefaultTimeLength": 90, "Id": 27, "Name": "Fitting", "NumDeducted": 1, "ProgramId": 9, "Category": "Other", "CategoryId": 17, "Subcategory": "Other", "SubcategoryId": 418 } ] };
data.SessionTypes.map(type => {
  console.log(type.Name);
});
```

Comment: thank you @0stone0 - that got me closer, but its also returns [undefined, undefined], anyway around that?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you're running.

Comment: added extra context and code, showing the results with [undefined]

Comment: Please see the second code snippet, thats 1:1 the code you've posted in the question. It works fine. There must be something else going on. Are you sure you've shared all the details?